# Will an rsync copy operation "fix" issues with invalid file block counts, or does it preserve everything exactly as the source?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, backup, rsync

**Here are the events surrounding my question, which may make things more relevant:**

I had a hard drive fail recently, to the point where neither Disk Utility or asr could fix the structure to a mountable point. The main issue reported was invalid block contents from a particular file, but it was probably more extensive than that since the problems I had been observing started before the file was put on the disk, and the first repair operation caused the system to be unable to boot up OSX in standard or safe mode. *Did I mention this is the primary boot disk?*

Fortunately I can still boot up recovery mode. All subsequent attempts to repair the volume failed, and despite being unable to mount the volume from the terminal in recovery mode, the data is readable from within single-user mode, and this is the context where I'm performing an rsync copy operation to back up personal data and some applications.

## Details:

- I'm performing an `rsync -avh` operation
- The source volume is corrupt, with "invalid block counts" as the Disk Utility reported problem
- The source and destination volumes are Apple_HFS (HFS+, Journaled)
- The source and destination volumes are on physically different hard disks

**Will the files written by rsync still contain block count errors on the destination drive?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finishing the operation and looking over the results, it's apparent that **no, block count errors will not be transposed to the destination drive**.

In fact, it will fail to read the files with block count errors and will not copy anything from them at all, skipping to the next file in the queue.